# Simultaneously change display parameters on all table view cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to implement a table view design where a user can click a button outside of a table view cell and the display mode of all the buttons should change. However this is not the 'selected' mode for a given cell (that will be yet a third state that becomes accessible via switching to this second state). What's the proper way to accomplish this?

I am using `dequeueReusableCellWith` so I don't want to simply cycle through every cell because some that are out of sight probably shouldn't be modified. I simply want any cell that is visible, or becomes visible, while the table view cell is in this second display mode to follow a second design rather than the first design.

The second design, for now, is being modified via a method I added to a subclass of `UITableViewCell` like so:

```
- (void) p_refreshDisplay {
    if (self.editing) {
        self.buttonToClearWidth.constant = 20;
        self.buttonToClearLeadingWidth.constant = 20;
    } else {
        self.buttonToClearWidth.constant = 0;
        self.buttonToClearLeadingWidth.constant = 0;
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to trigger this `p_refreshDisplay` for every visible (and to become visible) cell. It seems unwise to call this many times and refresh the table view. What would be the proper way to accomplish what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You do what should be done for any table view change:

1. Update your data model or some flag as needed.
2. Either call `reloadData` on the table view or call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` passing in `indexPathsForVisibleRows` as the list of rows to reload.
3. Implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to provide appropriate cells for the given data/flags.

It sounds like you should have a custom cell class that has one or more properties that can be set on the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so the cell can render itself properly based on the specified state.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing three things:

1. Establish some property that indicates the "mode" of the table, either a boolean or perhaps an enum if there are more than three states
2. Ensure that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` configures the cell appropriately based on the value of this property.  This will ensure that newly displayed cells are configured correctly.
3. When the "mode" changes you can use the tableview's `visibleCells` property to update any currently visible cells:

```
for cell in tableview.visibleCells {
    if let myCell = cell as? MyCustomCellClass {
        myCell.setButtonStyle()  
    }
}
```